# Laptop adds harsh noise to sound playback while running on battery

Tags: laptop, audio, power-supply, battery

I've looked at what others have said to those who asked with similar problems, and it seems to be a power supply issue. The louder the sound I'm trying to listen to is, or the higher the volume, the more harsh and noticeable the interfering noise is. So it is probably a noisy component on the interior of the laptop that gets amplified when I try to listen to something.

The problem is non-existent when the laptop is plugged into the power cord.

My question is how should I go about fixing this? Are there any easy fixes for this?

I have an ASUS X550L running Windows 10, and I've had this computer for something like 14 months before it started to have this problem (I'm outside of the warranty period now).

Comment: Try getting into whatever audio settings are relevant to your laptop, and MUTE all inputs you're not using. For example, on my PC I muted LINE-IN and CD-AUDIO-IN and noticed significant decrease in background noise. Worth a shot.

Comment: Odd, I would have honestly expected this to be the other way around, but yes, it's likely related to feedback from the power supply. Is there anything you can do to make this worse or better without changing the volume or power source?

Comment: @EthanZ no, there's nothing else I can do to make it worse other than increasing the volume. I think I figured it out though, my speakers were using Realtek HD Audio Manager, and when I went in and fiddled with the settings (specifically changing the sample rate and bit depth to a lower frequency) my problem was solved, no more noise. Such a strange problem..

Comment: Bad driver probably then.

Comment: I wonder if it's a grounding issue, since you said, "non-existent when the laptop is plugged into the power cord". Most laptop chargers tend to be grounded (the 3 prong ones).